# How can I configure persistence.xml to point to MongoDB

Tags: java, xml, mongodb, persistence, morphia

My project uses Morphia to map my Java entities to MongoDB. What I want to achieve is to create a persistence.xml and configure it so that I will not have to configure properties from source code. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Morphia doesn't use persistence.xml.  You'll have to use the annotations.